What are the maximum dimensions and weight per piece that can be loaded on a 737-800BCF (Boeng Converted Freighter)
The 737-800 Boeing Converted Freighter aircraft cargo specs are widely available on the Boeing and other related websites, but the actual per piece maximum dimensions and weight than can be fitted on a 737-800BCF are the subject of the question here.
